# Windows azure web role

Tags: azure-web-roles

We have planned to migrate our application to web role as web role splits the server traffics to other instances. We have some queries regarding that . Let me post it one by one.

1) Since web role involves multiple instances (redirecting to different servers at run time based on the number of instances created), what happens to my session related details which was maintained in one server (with inproc mode will get resides in iis ) when my next requests gets redirected to other server where my session related details wont be available know? Do the windows azure takes a copy of that too or do we need to manully handle?

2)Our application works like Presentation Layer makes a call to the web service which in turn queries the database and results are displayed accordingly (presentation -> webservice -> database). So when am making my presenataion layer as cloud service web role obvioulsy i would need to make my service also as a web role . Am i right?

2.1) If so, what happens when am making the request from presentation how the requests will get carried ?

2.2) Am having my database in a separated vm (not azure db) hosted in sql express when the service dynamically

creates multiple instances what happens to database part?

2.3) Shall we host service and presenation in same cloud service or different which will be preferrable one?

Comment: Can i get any updates

Comment: Can someone share suggestions?